# Custom label order?

Tags: trello

I am trying to categorize my project task in Trello. I created different labels for the different levels of Priority (how quickly this need to be finished) and Importance (how useful is the task).

Having those two labels easily seen and identifiable is important to me, so label seemed to be the perfect tool with the card coloration.

The problem is, Trello is ordering the labels by color, so for example:

```
[Priority: Medium (O)][Importance: Medium (O)][Cat A (G)]
[Priority: Medium (O)][Importance: Low (G)][Cat B (O)]
```

The colors seen will be the sames: Green, Orange, Orange, and I ll have to open both card to know what is what.

But if I were to order labels is a custom way, I could do something like:

- Priority: High (R)
- Priority: Medium (O)
- Priority: Low (G)
- Importance: High (R)
- Importance: Medium (O)
- Importance: Low (G)
- ... (standard ordering)

The card would appears as:

```
OOG
OGO
```

So I would know right away that the first task is more important, and I should take it before the second one.

Is there any way to do so? I am currently starting each card with a code to quickly identify priority and importance, along with labels, but that is cumbersome and feels wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, but currently custom Label order is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this issue by making the label's text visible.
For this, you can use a custom style [such as this one](https://userstyles.org/styles/143722/trello-label-names).

Answer (score -1):

I’m using 4 labels system: |IMPORTANT| |NOT IMPORTANT| and |URGENT| |NOT URGENT| . And i need specific colours for this. I solve this out temporarily - to get this done I’ve learn a bit about programming - if more people need this I will think about writing a plug-in for Chrome.